# SlidesJS not working on JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jsfiddle

I tried my own example on JSFiddle and it didn't work so I assume I had done something wrong.

But then I tried a couple of other examples such as [this](http://goo.gl/S4jVi) and none of them seem to work.

Does SlidesJS just not work on JSFiddle or is it something specific to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the console you will see:

```
GET http://slidesjs.com/examples/simple/js/slides.min.jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
```

which means your `slides.min.jquery.js` file is not loading (404 File Not Found).

Use `http://slidesjs.com/js/jquery.slides.min.js` instead, also the main method is no `.slides()` but `.slidesjs()` , see [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bzrDK/51/) .